# Invoke a REST service from PL/SQL

Tags: rest

I am trying to make a HTTP Request from PL/Sql. I need to use access token for authentication rather than username and password. Please suggest the standard API or code to use to pass the access token.

Code:

```
    DECLARE
        obj           json;
        val_          json_value;
        el_val      BOOLEAN;
        req            utl_http.req;
        res            utl_http.resp;
        url             VARCHAR2(4000) := 'http://acdl-act- 
        dev.azurewebsites.net/apiconn/push';
        name        VARCHAR2(4000);
    buffer        CLOB;
    l_chunk     VARCHAR2(32000);
    content      CLOB := '{ "User_Name":"John","City":"Delhi", "Operation":"I"';
BEGIN
    req := utl_http.begin_request( url, 'POST', ' HTTP/1.1');
    utl_http.set_header( req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0');
    utl_http.set_header( req,'content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    utl_http.set_header( req,'Content-Length', length(content));
-- utl_http.set_authentication(r => req, username    => p_user_name, password    => p_pwd,scheme      => 'Basic',for_proxy   => false);
-- Need to use access token for authentication ex: 'adghjcjhdnmfbhjd367dsbasfkjhkdfsf38789734bcff'
        utl_http.write_text(req, content);
        res := utl_http.get_response(req);
      -- process the response from the HTTPS call
        BEGIN
            LOOP
                utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
            END LOOP;
            utl_http.end_response(res);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
                utl_http.end_response(res);
        END;
END ws_call_code;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, but incase someone is looking for the same information.  I just needed to access a REST webservice using an OAuth token and I just needed to set a header with my token, utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization', l_token).

Answer (score -2):

Reading Oracle documentation'
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS71082

The procedure UTL_HTTP.SET_AUTHENTICATION has the following usage note
*

> The supported authentication schemes are HTTP basic and Amazon S3
>   authentication.

*